# Working chevron icons for jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to learn how to do this. I've posted a few times today sorry about that.

The problem: Tab is selected and chevron changes from down to up (great) but when another tab is selected the previous tab doesn't go back to default down. I am using up and down classes to add the chevron image icons.

jQuery

```
// Chevron icons move up and down 
$(function() {
//Add down to all .chevrons
$(".section a .chevron").addClass('down'); 

//Toggle up/down classes
$(".section a").click(function() {
    var $chevron = $(this).find('.chevron'); 
    $chevron.toggleClass("down up");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just select all and and remove the up class on click.
Something like:

```
$(".section a").click(function() {
    $(".section a .chevron").removeClass('up').addClass('down'); 
    var $chevron = $(this).find('.chevron'); 
    $chevron.toggleClass("down up");
});
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. However now when you click on a section that is already opened with a chevron up. The chevron stays up.

Comment: Ok so you want it to close too, try something like this:

   $(".section a").click(function() {
        var $chevron = $(this).find('.chevron');
        var opened =  $chevron.hasClass( "up" );
        $(".section a .chevron").removeClass('up').addClass('down'); 
        $chevron.addClass((opened) ? down : up));
    });

Comment: Sorry I'm getting syntax errors I can't figure out. Unexpected on the last line.

Comment: Sorry...
$(".section a").click(function() { var $chevron = $(this).find('.chevron'); var opened = $chevron.hasClass( "up" ); $(".section a .chevron").removeClass('up').addClass('down'); $chevron.addClass((opened) ? down : up); });